# nodejs npm-migration create multiple tables with one migration

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, migration

I am new to npm-migration for nodejs and I am trying to create multiple tables with one migration instead of having multiple migrations for creating all my tables.
I have tried this:

```
"up": company_type_up + company_up,
"down": company_down + company_type_down,
```

Also this:

```
module.exports = {
"up":
    function(pool, cb){
        pool.multipleStatements = true;
        var query =
            company_type_up +
            company_up;
        pool.query(query, function(err, res){
            cb();
        });
    },
"down":
    function(pool, cb){
        var query =
            company_down + company_type_down;
        pool.query(query, function(err, res){
            cb();
        });
    },
}
```

If you want to see my statements here you are:

```
var company_type_up =
"CREATE TABLE company_type(" +
"_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
"name VARCHAR(60), " +
"description VARCHAR(500) " +
"); ";

var company_type_down =
"DROP TABLE company_type; ";

var company_up =
"CREATE TABLE company(" +
"_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
"name VARCHAR(60), " +
"description VARCHAR(500), " +
"country VARCHAR(100), " +
"state VARCHAR(100), " +
"city VARCHAR(100), " +
"address VARCHAR(300), " +
"phone1 VARCHAR(60), " +
"phone2 VARCHAR(60), " +
"email VARCHAR(100), " +
"tax_name VARCHAR(300), " +
"tax_number VARCHAR(200), " +
"firm_name VARCHAR(300)" +
"); ";

var company_down =
"DROP TABLE company; ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I refactored my code and I have this a approach:

```
"up":
    function(pool, cb){
        pool.query(schema.company_type_up, function(err, res){if(err) console.log(err); });
        pool.query(schema.company_up, function(err, res){if(err) console.log(err);});

        cb();
    },
"down":
    function(pool, cb){
        pool.query(schema.company_down, function(err, res){if(err) console.log(err);});
        pool.query(schema.company_type_down, function(err, res){if(err) console.log(err);});

        cb();
    },
```

Is working, but I am sure there is a better way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one migration that can do that but you can use one command line with `&&` .

For instance:

```
npx db-migrate create first-table --sql-file && db-migrate create second-table --sql-file && db-migrate create third-table --sql-file
```